# How to use an API in R to be able to get data for storing into a db?

Tags: r, database, sqlite, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to figure out how to get data in R for the purposes of making it into a table that I can store into a database like sql.

```
API <- "https://covidtrackerapi.bsg.ox.ac.uk/api/v2/stringency/date-range/{2020-01-01}/{2020-06-30}"
oxford_covid <- GET(API)
```

I then try to parse this data and make it into a dataframe but when I do so I get the errors of:
"Error: Columns 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 178 more must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair." and "Error: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes. * Size 2: Columns `deaths`, `casesConfirmed`, and `stringency`. * Size 176: Columns `..2020.12.27`, `..2020.12.28`, `..2020.12.29`, and"

I am not sure if there is a better approach or how to parse this. Is there a method or approach? I am not having much luck online.

Comment: At least one problem: `{}` are not included in the API call (assume they signify "substitution" in the doc). Suggest calling the API directly in the browser to familiarize with the results.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus yes I know the {} not included, was just putting this as example of where date goes, the trouble is not here but later on

Comment: BTW, for future questions, when you have an error message and give us the error message, it really helps to know what code you used to cause that error. For instance, it isn't clear to me if you're using `read.table`, `read.csv`, `readr::*`, etc. While all of those are still the wrong answer for this type of data (see my answer), the point is that we don't know what you've tried, so helping you fix your code is improbable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to take the JSON return from that API and call `read.table` or something on it. Don't do that, JSON should be parsed by JSON tools (such as `jsonlite::parse_json`).

Some work on that URL.

```r
js <- jsonlite::parse_json(url("https://covidtrackerapi.bsg.ox.ac.uk/api/v2/stringency/date-range/2020-01-01/2020-06-30"))
lengths(js)
#     scale countries      data 
#         3       183       182 

str(js, max.level = 2, list.len = 3)
# List of 3
#  $ scale    :List of 3
#   ..$ deaths        :List of 2
#   ..$ casesConfirmed:List of 2
#   ..$ stringency    :List of 2
#  $ countries:List of 183
#   ..$ : chr "ABW"
#   ..$ : chr "AFG"
#   ..$ : chr "AGO"
#   .. [list output truncated]
#  $ data     :List of 182
#   ..$ 2020-01-01:List of 183
#   ..$ 2020-01-02:List of 183
#   ..$ 2020-01-03:List of 183
#   .. [list output truncated]
```

So this is rather large. Since you're hoping for a `data.frame`, I'm going to look at `js$data` only; `js$countries` looks relatively uninteresting,

```r
str(unlist(js$countries))
#  chr [1:183] "ABW" "AFG" "AGO" "ALB" "AND" "ARE" "ARG" "AUS" "AUT" "AZE" "BDI" "BEL" "BEN" "BFA" "BGD" "BGR" "BHR" "BHS" "BIH" "BLR" "BLZ" "BMU" "BOL" "BRA" "BRB" "BRN" "BTN" "BWA" "CAF" "CAN" "CHE" "CHL" "CHN" "CIV" "CMR" "COD" "COG" "COL" "CPV" ...
```

and does not correlate with the `js$data`. The `js$scale` might be interesting, but I'll skip it for now.

My first go-to for joining data like this into a `data.frame` is one of the following, depending on your preference for R dialects:

```r
do.call(rbind.data.frame, list_of_frames)  # base R
dplyr::bind_rows(list_of_frames)           # tidyverse
data.table::rbindlist(list_of_frames)      # data.table
```

But we're going to run into problems. Namely, there are entries that are `NULL`, when R would prefer that they be something (such as `NA`).

```r
str(js$data[[1]][1])
# List of 2
#  $ ABW:List of 8
#   ..$ date_value            : chr "2020-01-01"
#   ..$ country_code          : chr "ABW"
#   ..$ confirmed             : NULL                # <--- problem
#   ..$ deaths                : NULL
#   ..$ stringency_actual     : int 0
#   ..$ stringency            : int 0
#   ..$ stringency_legacy     : int 0
#   ..$ stringency_legacy_disp: int 0
```

So we need to iterate over each of those and replace `NULL` with `NA`. Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy tool to recursively go through lists of lists (even `rapply` doesn't work well in my tests), so we'll be a little brute-force here with a triple-`lapply`:

Long-story-short,

```r
str(js$data[[1]][[1]])
# List of 8
#  $ date_value            : chr "2020-01-01"
#  $ country_code          : chr "ABW"
#  $ confirmed             : NULL
#  $ deaths                : NULL
#  $ stringency_actual     : int 0
#  $ stringency            : int 0
#  $ stringency_legacy     : int 0
#  $ stringency_legacy_disp: int 0
jsdata <-
  lapply(js$data, function(z) {
    lapply(z, function(y) {
      lapply(y, function(x) if (is.null(x)) NA else x)
    })
  })
str(jsdata[[1]][[1]])
# List of 8
#  $ date_value            : chr "2020-01-01"
#  $ country_code          : chr "ABW"
#  $ confirmed             : logi NA
#  $ deaths                : logi NA
#  $ stringency_actual     : int 0
#  $ stringency            : int 0
#  $ stringency_legacy     : int 0
#  $ stringency_legacy_disp: int 0
```

(Technically, if we know that it's going to be integers, we should use `NA_integer_`. Fortunately, R and its dialects are able to work with this shortcut, as we'll see in a second.)

After that, we can do a double-dive rbinding and get back to the frame-making I discussed a couple of steps ago. Choose one of the following, whichever dialect you prefer:

```r
alldat <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,
                  lapply(jsdata, function(z) do.call(rbind.data.frame, z)))
alldat <- dplyr::bind_rows(purrr::map(jsdata, dplyr::bind_rows))
alldat <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(jsdata, data.table::rbindlist))
```

For simplicity, I'll show the first (base R) version:

```r
tail(alldat)
#                date_value country_code confirmed deaths stringency_actual stringency stringency_legacy stringency_legacy_disp
# 2020-06-30.AND 2020-06-30          AND       855     52             42.59      42.59             65.47                  65.47
# 2020-06-30.ARE 2020-06-30          ARE     48667    315             72.22      72.22             83.33                  83.33
# 2020-06-30.AGO 2020-06-30          AGO       284     13             75.93      75.93             83.33                  83.33
# 2020-06-30.ALB 2020-06-30          ALB      2535     62             68.52      68.52             78.57                  78.57
# 2020-06-30.ABW 2020-06-30          ABW       103      3             47.22      47.22             63.09                  63.09
# 2020-06-30.AFG 2020-06-30          AFG     31507    752             78.70      78.70             76.19                  76.19
```

And if you're curious about the `$scale`,

```r
do.call(rbind.data.frame, js$scale)
#                min     max
# deaths           0  127893
# casesConfirmed   0 2633466
# stringency       0     100

## or

data.table::rbindlist(js$scale, idcol="id")
#                id   min     max
#            <char> <int>   <int>
# 1:         deaths     0  127893
# 2: casesConfirmed     0 2633466
# 3:     stringency     0     100

## or

dplyr::bind_rows(js$scale, .id = "id")
```